# Vlookup or Index Match a sequence of cells - 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I've got two spreadsheets, sheet 1 is a sort of master list which has a participant number, a variable amount of weight lost, and a period (the month but it's expressed simply as a number 1, 2, 3, 4 (and sometimes it starts at 0 for some reason :/) see attached).

Sheet 2 has the actual dates, and some other variables (those aren't important right now). I'd like a formula that matches the participant numbers, and puts the percent weight loss for that row - so if there's 13 dates for 00000021 (10/1/2015-10/1/2016), it will return the C2:C14 basically. The number of dates can vary from 1-13 however.

My first thought was Index Match, but that of course only pulled 1 variable because the match was the same - the participant number. Then I thought ah ha! I'll add the period to the participant number to create a variable that has the participant number, and the period, then vlookup with a plus 1 to the variable I'm looking up, but that's only giving me the first percent weight loss cell. Progress, but not good enough haha.

I can get the periods to all start at 0 with an `=if(D2>0, D2-1, D2)`, or the other way around, to all start with 1.

Perhaps something that matches if the period equals 0-12 or 1-13?
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance, have a great day :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the period column in your second worksheet with the countif function given below. This counts the number of participants there are in column A above a given row.

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

Then use a `VLOOKUP` function the find the right participant and period row and output the weight in worksheet 2.

Comment: Ah I don't think that works, just outputs counts from 0-13 (which should be 0-12), while the number of dates can be variable - sometimes only 3 or 4, or the full amount. Haha close! And thanks for the imput :).
Oh think it should be ```=countif(A$2:A2,A2)```

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake. Hope it works out for you.